Is K-distribution a special case of variance-gamma distribution?
Here we consider K-distribution, generalized K-distribution and variance-gamma distribution whose density functions are given by $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ respectively:
\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &= \frac{2b}{\Gamma(v)}(\sqrt{bx})^{v-1}K_{v-1}(2\sqrt{bx}),\quad b,v>0,\\
f_2(x) &= \frac{2}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\left(\frac{\alpha\beta}{\mu}\right)^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}x^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-1}K_{\alpha-\beta}\left(2\sqrt{\frac{\alpha\beta x}{\mu}}\right), \quad \alpha,\beta,\mu>0,\\
f_3(x)&=\frac{\gamma^{2\lambda}|x-\mu|^{\lambda-1/2}K_{\lambda-1/2}\left(\alpha|x-\mu|\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\lambda)(2\alpha)^{\lambda-1/2}}e^{\beta(x-\mu)},\quad \mu,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \lambda>0, \gamma=\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}>0,
\end{align*}
where $K_a(\cdot)$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
From K-distribution, I want to verify the statement "K-distribution is a special case of variance-gamma distribution", but fail to reparametrize $f_3$ to reproduce $f_1$ or $f_2$. Hence, is K-distribution or generalized K-distribution a special case of variance-gamma distribution? Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.
